# Differential entropy from samples: $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} p(x) \log(p(x)) dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, probability-theory, indefinite-integrals, information-theory

**Question**

I am trying to calculate the differential entropy of a probability distribution with an unknown probability density function $p(x)$ but for which I have multiple samples. The random variable, $X$, is multivariate: an image composed of dependent univariate random variables (pixels) $X_{x,y}$.

The differential entropy is given by:
$$-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} p(x) \log(p(x)) dx$$

So far, I have tried computing the anti-derivate by hand, using wolfram alpha, using Lambert W functions, all with no success.
By knowing the anti-derivative, it might be possible to use Monte-Carlo integration (or other approximate methods) to approximate the integral using samples.

I am posting in a mathematics forum so that maybe someone has the tools to solve this integral or at least explain why it can't be solved.
Intuitively, since we know that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} p(x) dx = 1$ it feels like there should be a way.

**Related approaches:**

There are two main approaches in the literature:

1. To bin/discretize the continuous variable, compute the histogram and
   use the discrete entropy as a proxy;
2. Use a kernel method to
   approximate the density at one point with a normal distribution with
   mean equals sample mean and a chosen fixed variance.

While these approaches are sensible for univariate variables and even for (mostly) independent multivariate variables, they will not work well in the case of images (strong dependencies).

Comment: First, your formula is missing the minus sign. Second, I don't get what are you trying to do. It would only make sense to try an analytical approach if you have a formula for your density. Even more puzzling are your remarks about you application. Even for univariate variables, if you want to capture the dependences you'd need to consider a multivariate density (making the problem even harder). Also, fi you are working with digital images, I don't know why are you using differential entropies instead of the discrete (true) entropy.

Comment: Thanks, added the minus sign. I want to to consider the multivariate density. The reason for not using discrete entropy is that it is impossible to count the joint states since all images are different. My application is that I want to measure the information content of a set of images.

Comment: You should know that differential entropy has turned out to be a poor entropy measure for continuous random variables.  An alternative is called _relative entropy_ (also called K-L divergence or cross-entropy).  See also the search results for "[differential entropy](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?page=2&tab=Newest&q=%22differential%20entropy%22) in _Cross Validated_.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up finding some work on the topic here https://arxiv.org/abs/0809.0853 and in it's references if anyone is interested.

Comment: Also here https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/016794738790065X